# Location data access XCode13

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

I'm trying to add a request to access users location data in Xcode 13 for an iOS app but I see apple have removed the info.plist file - where do we add this request now?

Comment: Not sure what "removed the info.plist file" means.  I am thinking you probably do have one. If you click on your target app, then click on the Info tab, you should see the content of Info.plist.  You would need to add the key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and your description.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 13 and the project has no info.plist file present. 
Thanks for the tip